# Altering a View to add a column as bit not null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to add a column to a view using `ALTER VIEW` but it keeps saying 'The column is invalid'. I need the column to be BIT NOT NULL. How would I go about doing this?  Thank you all!

```
SELECT dbo.tbl_skins.skinName, dbo.tbl_prefs.PersonID, dbo.tbl_prefs[columnName] etc... 
FROM dbo.tbl_prefs 
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_skins 
   ON dbo.tbl_prefs.skinId = dbo.tbl_skins.skinId
```

I didn't add the rest of the columns because the rest are all from `dbo.tbl_prefs`. The only one that is different is that first one that reads `dbo.tbl_skins.skinName`.

Upon opening the table I see,

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [column1],[column2], etc... FROM [table_name].
```

All I'm trying to do is add a new column of type BIT, NOT NULL to the table (`dbo.tbl_prefs`) and the same to the view (`dbo.qry_prefs`).

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using MS SQL Server Management Studio 17

Comment: Show us the ALTER VIEW statement. (Perhaps simplified.)

Comment: Perhaps if you showed the complete `ALTER VIEW`, or at least enough of one that *demonstrates the error*, we may be able to help. At the moment, we have to *guess* what you've written as the column definition.

Comment: Right now I have:  `SELECT TOP (1000) [column 1], [column 2], [column 3], etc... FROM [projects].[dbo].[qry.prefs]`

Comment: Full stop in a table name, eek. You're not really making it easy for us to help you by giving us as little information as possible here. It sounds like you are confusing adding a field to a table and adding a field to a view that queries the underlying table.

Comment: are you referring just one  table ? 
Try putting schema in front of all tables.

Comment: Sorry, I've never worked with views before, just tables, so all I know is the query that I just posted. :(

Comment: Yes but you didn't post the query. You posted half a query. How can anyone give you suggestions? Update your post, not a comment, include your full query for the view and the table structure and you will get a resolution. Otherwise, we can only guess.

Comment: The whole query I have in the view is just what I posted, except (more specifically) there are 30 columns

Comment: What is the specific new line that you added to the view when you did the ALTER VIEW?   Does the new column that you are adding exist in the table that your view is selecting from?

Comment: I tried: `ALTER VIEW [dbo].[qry_prefs] AS SELECT [newColumn] BIT NOT NULL FROM [projects].[dbo].[qry_prefs]`

Comment: Yeah I tried casting the column to make it a bit not null, but I think I wrote the syntax wrong.  Sorry, I haven't used SQL in a while let alone worked with views.  I deleted the query but I think I wrote it like `ALTER VIEW [dbo].[qry_prefs] AS SELECT CAST(bit, not null) [newColumn] FROM [projects].[dbo].[qry_prefs]` But i'm pretty certain that's wrong.

Comment: A view is just a stored SQL query against one or more tables.   This "new column" is sourced from what table column?  is that table column also a bit?  are you hardcoding a 0? are you using a case statment to determine the "bit" value?  would just `coalesce(tableName.column,0)` as newColumn work assuming tableName.column is of a bit datattype?  Post sample data from tables and expected results of your view as well as the view DDL and we can help.

Comment: Ohh okay. Yes it is stored against 2 tables I believe. It's stored against one and then says `FROM dbo.tbl_prefs INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_skins ON dbo.tbl_prefs.skinId = dbo.tblskins.skinId`

Comment: Please edit your question and put the entire view in there, starting from create view ... or alter view ...

Answer (score 1):

> *Yeah I tried casting the column to make it a bit not null, but I think I wrote the syntax wrong. Sorry, I haven't used SQL in a while
>   let alone worked with views. I deleted the query but I think I wrote
>   it like ALTER VIEW [dbo].[qry_prefs] AS SELECT CAST(bit, not null)
>   [newColumn] FROM [projects].[dbo].[qry_prefs] But i'm pretty certain
>   that's wrong.*

You are trying to add a column to a view that you then want to retrieve again from that view. That makes no sense.

Try something like this

Assuming that your view is called qry_prefs and you want to add a blank bit column.

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[qry_prefs] AS 
  SELECT dbo.tbl_skins.skinName, 
         dbo.tbl_prefs.PersonID, 
         dbo.tbl_prefs.[columnName],
         etc... 
         convert(bit, null) as newColumn
  FROM dbo.tbl_prefs 
    INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_skins ON dbo.tbl_prefs.skinId = dbo.tbl_skins.skinId
```

Make it some easier for yourself by using aliases

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[qry_prefs] AS 
  SELECT s.skinName, 
         p.PersonID, 
         p.[columnName],
         etc... 
         convert(bit, null) as newColumn
  FROM dbo.tbl_prefs p 
    INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_skins s ON p.skinId = s.skinId
```

**EDIT: from the comments it seems you need to add the field to the table and to the view**

That can be done like this

```
alter table [dbo].[tbl_prefs]
add newColumn bit null
```

now add this field to the view like this

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[qry_prefs] AS 
  SELECT s.skinName, 
         p.PersonID, 
         p.[columnName],
         etc... 
         p.newColumn
  FROM dbo.tbl_prefs p 
    INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_skins s ON p.skinId = s.skinId
```

Comment: The dbo.qry_prefs view is coming from a table called dbo.tbl_prefs.  Sorry, I should've mentioned that.

Comment: @Anthony This should help you alter your view, but you do not give us much information to help you so if this does not helps than give us more info like requested in many comments already

Comment: I apologize for all the confusion :(. Again, i'm sort of new to this, so it's a little confusing to me, but I think I can get it. I appreciate all your input!  I don't know how much more info you need. Like, you need the query from the actual table & the view as well? The table that it's coming from is just `SELECT TOP (1000) [column1], [column2], [column3], etc... FROM [projects].[dbo].[tbl_prefs]` and I earlier wrote a query to add a column like: `ALTER TABLE [table_name] ADD [newColumnName] BIT NOT NULL`.

Comment: @Anthony We need the create statement of the view and we need to know what you want to alter in it

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I didn't use a create statement, I just have the table opened with all the columns selected. There's 30 columns and most of them are of type bit, not null. and a few of them are of text, null & int, not null. Unfortunately that's all I know about how the table was created. The table was previously created already, I'm just adding to it.

Comment: @Anthony So there is no view at all ? Do you want to add this new column to the table and not to a view ? Can you edit your question and describe exact what you want to do and what you have done so far ?

Comment: Oh no, there is a view. That's what I've been referring to this whole time. I was just saying, I need this new column added to the table AND the view. I already have it in the table the way I need, `[newColumn](bit, not null)`. I just need that same thing in the view as well, and my issue was that I hit a snag when I was trying to `ALTER VIEW` because it wasn't as easy as when I did `ALTER TABLE` in the table.

Comment: @Anthony I updated my answer At the bottom you can find how to do that

Comment: no problem, the key is that when you alter a view, you have to write the whole view again including the change, not just the change like with a table

Comment: Yeah when I did that it would say "invalid column name" because it didn't have a type, but adding the type wasn't the same as it was in the table, e.g. `ALTER TABLE [table_name] ADD [new_column] BIT NOT NULL`. So I got quite confused.

Comment: Is there a way to add the data type to a column in a view? I tried `CAST` but I don't think I got the syntax correct

Comment: yes, look at my first queries in my answer. Convert(bit, p.newcolumn) would do the trick

Comment: But it is very unusual to change the data type in a view. Why do you need this ? Just adding the field to the view is enough, the data type of the column from its table will be used here

Answer (score -1):

try this----

create table #temp (
  col_1   varchar(15) not null,
  col_2   varchar(15) not null
);

create view tq84_v as select col_1, col_2 from

Comment: No bit column, nor is the query complete. And you can't create a view using a temp table. So not particularly useful for OP.